# Wordpress with SQL Server backend stores "????" instead of Cyrillic characters

Tags: wordpress, sql-server-2008

I have a wordpress installation on sql server 2008 r2. I am not a php man myself, so I'm not really sure how to attack the php side.

On the sql server side I can see question marks being stored, so this is not just a presentation issue.

I am thinking maybe the insert itself does not have an `N` before the string.

Can anyone point me to where I can start looking in the php files, or even better is there is a known solution for this issue?

**Edit:** I already checked and all fields are nvarchar.

**Edit 2:** I just manually inserted the data into the DB and it is stored correctly.

Comment: Are you on utf8 encoding for your database?

Comment: Yes. If I do an insert through management studio, everything works. If I insert the data manually into the DB, I can view the post in wordpress and I see the Cyrillic characters. The issue is the insert itself I believe.

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins?

Comment: @desbest - Maybe you can point me to where in the code the values are put from the POST to the $post object. Maybe if I add 'N' before the string, the insert will be in unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `wp-includes/wp-db.php` file.

Wpdb is the core database object used for db operations.

Comment: Yes, whatever. That's what I would call bounty hunting :) Enjoy.